# Ionic 2 redirecting users after login

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to redirect to *TabsPage* after a user logs in using Auth0.

The authentication is working and `*ngIf="!auth.authenticated()"` `*ngIf="auth.authenticated()"` is working too, but if I use `this.auth.authenticated()` in */app/app.component.ts* it always returns **false**.

This is the structure:

- LoginPage
- TabsPage

  - HomePage
  - RepositoriesPage
  - ...

I followed this tutorial to add Auth0 https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic2

Comment: Can you show us your typescript code? Might be f.e. an async issue?

Comment: Does your `app.module.ts` look like [this one](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-ionic2-samples/blob/master/01-Login/src/app/app.module.ts)? I've experienced the same issue when migrating to RC0 and it was because of the `tokenGetter ` not being properly defined.

Comment: @sebaferreras I was missing some code (imports) but now that I have the exact code as the example my browser gets unresponsive